# Why aren't American cars as popular worldwide as e.g. Japanese cars?

Tags: automotive-engineering

I heard that the Japanese reverse-engineered American ones and produced them cheaper but I don't know the engineering/business reasons behind the phenomenon.

Comment: Because they are too big for the roads in some countries...

Comment: I have a 03 Honda Accord with 285k miles on it. Changed the oil every 6k miles. Nothing more. Among my cars it's the most reliable. Can any US car do that. I had a Ford Expedition 2000. Had to give to charity in 2015. They didn't want to tow it.

Answer (score 1):

Before Japan got into the business of exporting cars to the world, they studied other car designs very carefully and set about designing their own cars in a way that incorporated what they had learned, and avoided the more obvious design errors that they found. Then, they very systematically revised their own designs year after year, solving the problems that they themselves were responsible for, so their designs got better and better.

Since fuel is very expensive in the orient and the cities very cramped, their domestic designs were as compact and as fuel-efficient as possible, and this is also what they exported. So they entered the international market building small, inexpensive and relatively simple cars and used that segment of the marketplace to learn in. With time they incrementally increased the performance and complexity of their designs as they got better and better at building cars.

American car makers during that time (the late 1960's through the mid-1980's) were not used to having competition and so were not driven to excel and improve year after year, and cheap oil meant not worrying about fuel efficiency- until the first oil crises hit. Then they found themselves with almost no engineering experience building small, fuel-efficient cars, and their initial designs were widely seen as incompetent and therefore uncompetitive. In comparison, the Japanese designs became popular in the American market and remain so today.

Comment: Sounds a bit like how they got the British bike industry... is that a bee? No it’s an fs1e...

Comment: @SolarMike, you are exactly correct!

Comment: Japan is not in the "orient."

Comment: in common useage in the usa, it is *oriental*.

Answer (score 1):

The single most important factor was quality. 
The Japanese hired American quality consultants and LISTENED to them. The American manufacturers did not ; they just kept making the same (quality) mistakes until the late 70's when the Americans realized the Japanese were going to put them out of business. The principal quality consultants were J M Juran and Deming. One title I have handy is "Quality Planning and Analysis" ,JM Juran and FM Gryna. There are other books . Years ago the was an educational TV program , I believe by Deming. He talked about the years he tried to talk to important American manufacturers with no success.  The ASQC ( American Society for Quality Control) will have many publications available. Japanese industry broadly accepted QC,QA principles. A QC specialist,retired from Kodak once told me Fuji 's excellent quality did more than anything to essentially put Kodak out of business...One car story, my first Japanese car was a 85 Nissan 300 ZX, used with 50,000 miles. I opened the hood and the engine was CLEAN, I had owned many American cars and I thought they HAD to leak oil. The cars I had owned included Cadillac, Lincoln, Imperial, so they were as good as American manufacturers could make them , with poor QC. Look in Wikipedia for" W Edward Deming" for more of the story of how Japan started to make better products than US car companys.

Comment: There was a common saying in the UK back in the 70s: The good thing about Ford cars is that replacement parts are cheap compared with other brands. The bad thing is you will need to buy a lot of them.

Comment: It is a mentality differrence. Most american companies see that their  only target is to make money. While the culture of buildinc communities in companies is a big factor elsewhere. If you look at only money it is easy to say we dominate lets pump money. If that is not your only objective or your playing catch  its easier to take a broader view.